# Displaying element only once after multiple clicks

Tags: jquery

I am making a chat application which shows a list of online users so when I click on one online user a chat window opens and again when I click on the same user again a new window is opened. What I want is when the user clicks again on the same user new chat window should not be generated it should display the one which was opened earlier. What would be the condition for that. Here is jquery function

```
$(".shout_msg").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var name = $(this).text();

  $('body').append("<div id = 'd-"+id+"' class = 'shout_box1'></div>");
  $("#d-"+id).append("<div id = 'h-"+id+"' class = 'header1'>'"+name+"'</div>");
  $("#h-"+id).append("<div id = 'c-"+id+"' class='close_btn1'>&nbsp;</div>")
  $("#d-"+id).append("<div id = 't-"+id+"' class = 'toggle_chat1'></div>");
  $("#t-"+id).append("<div id = 'm-"+id+"' class = 'message_box1'></div>");
  $("#t-"+id).append("<div id = 'u-"+id+"' class = 'user_info1'></div>");
  $("#u-"+id).append('<input name = "shout_message" id = "s-'+id+'" type = "text" placeholder = "Type Message Hit Enter" />');

  $("#s-"+id).keypress(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 13) {
      var msg = $("#s-"+id).val();
      // msg = msg.replace(":)","<img src = 'smilenew.gif'/>");
      var sender = "<?php echo $user_check?>";
      var receiver = name;
      var dt = new Date();
      var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

      $("#m-"+id).append('<p class = "shout_msg" id = "'+count+'">'+sender+':'+msg+'<span class = "time">'+time+'</span></p>');
      $.ajax({
        url: "insertdatanew.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
          'sender': sender,
          'receiver': receiver,
          'msg': msg,
          'time': time
        },
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'Y') {
            alert("Successful insertion");
          }
        }
      });

      $("#m-"+id).scrollTop($("#m-"+id)[0].scrollHeight);
      //count++;
      $("#s-"+id).val("");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if that div already exists..

```
if($('#divid').length){
     // dont append
} else {
     // append
}
```

Comment: Hey I didn't get you. Can you give me the with respect to my code. I am totally new to jquery.